# Java Child Classloader overwrite parent

Tags: java, classloader

Is there a way to overwrite classes / jar files inside a child classloader.

Currently I want to run another Jar version of inside my child classloader which is already loaded in my parent classloader. Is there any possible way of doing this?

Comment: You can always modify the bytecode of the classes to load, so they load with some kind of prefix.

Comment: Can you explain it in more details?

Comment: If your new class loader is not supposed to use the classes of another existing class loader, why do you make it a child of the old class loader?

Comment: Make sure that a class is loaded by one class loader. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650568/diffrenence-between-appclassloader-and-systemclassloader/34659914#34659914

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve a self-made problem. If you don’t want your class loader to delegate to the parent, don’t create it with that parent in the first place. Here is a simple example of a class loading another version of itself. All it has to care about, is not to use its own class loader as parent of the new one, but the parent of its own loader

```
       parent loader
        ↑         ↑
my own loader    the new loader
```

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class Reloader {
  static {
    System.out.println("Initializing one version of the class");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ReflectiveOperationException {
    Class<?> myClass=Reloader.class;
    ClassLoader myLoader=myClass.getClassLoader();
    URL[] u={ myClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() };
    // don't use our class loader but its parent loader:
    try(URLClassLoader newLoader=new URLClassLoader(u, myLoader.getParent())) {
      // load another version of our class in a different loader context
      Class<?> newVersion = newLoader.loadClass(myClass.getName());
      // see: it's a different class now
      System.out.println(myClass==newVersion);
      // having the same name
      System.out.println(myClass.getName()==newVersion.getName());
      newVersion.newInstance();// trigger initializer
    }
  }
}
```

[Online test on Ideone](https://ideone.com/8WmXtD):

> stdout
>
> ```
> Initializing one version of the class
> false
> true
> Initializing one version of the class
> ```